# JavaFX ScrollPane memory leak software pipeline

Tags: java, memory-leaks, javafx, scrollpane

I have a simple code and run with **-Dprism.order=sw** using jdk8_45:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(new ScrollPane());

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Test FX ScrollPane");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Run VisualVM and have the following: greates object is **int[] - 9-10MB**

Than just resizing window many times and look at VisualVM with out calling GC: greates object is **int[] - 400-500MB**

After calling GC: greates object is **int[] - 140-150MB**

If heap dump and look at that int[] - it's images, and over time they become more and more.

If run with **-Dprism.order=es2** it's all right.

Any solutions for this? Thanks